# Access ngModel's parent object inside directive link

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

After requiring ngModel in my directive and using the 4th argument ngModel inside my link function I can access the value of the bound model. In my instance this bound value is product.id (inside an ng-repeat).

How can I now, from my link function read other values of my product object?

`<input type="hidden" ng-model="product.id" my-directive">`

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
   restrict: "a",
   require: "ngModel",
   link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
       // Here I want to read product.name, product.price etc
   }
});
```

Comment: I feel like you are trying to do something wrong to even want this functionality in a directive bound to `<input type="hidden">`. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have to set the default value for a select2 box that uses AJAX to search for products. Which is id=product.id and text=product.name.

Comment: Then why do you need `<input type="hidden">`? Default value is set by setting the vm model for the input

Comment: You have to use a hidden input for Select2 if you want to use AJAX functionalities. And as you have to set the initialValue inside the select2() function this is the only correct way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind product with input data tag;
Like:-

```
<input type="hidden" ng-model="product.id" data-product="product" my-directive">
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
   restrict: "a",
scope{
product: "=product"
},
link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
       // Here I want to read product.name, product.price etc
       //Here scope.product will return all the values

   }
});
```